# Cannot open the file after writing xlsx file using R openxlsx package

Tags: r, r-xlsx

At first, I tried to read and write xlsx files in R (while comparing the output between the `xlsx` and `openxlsx` packages).

I work on mac os.

It worked well to read xlsx files using the `read.xlsx()` from both packages. 
However, when it comes to writing a new file, only the `xlsx::write.xlsx()` worked.

To be more exact, the `openxlsx::write.xlsx()` command gave no error, and an xlsx file was successfully saved, but when I tried to open the file using Numbers (by double clicking on the file in the folder), an error message popped up telling me the file cannot be opened.

I tried different data frames, but the results remained the same. To show an example, please refer to the following line which I took directly from R help page. It should work but does not work for me.

```
write.xlsx(iris, file = "writeXLSX1.xlsx", colNames = TRUE, borders = "columns")
```

Anyone tell me what the problem is? I tried to google for old threads but it seems no one is discussing this problem. I know in many similar threads people suggested changing packages, okay...before that, can you tell me what the limitations of `openxlsx` are?

Comment: Not able to reproduce the problem with `openxlsx_4.0.17` on `R 3.4.0`

Comment: well, I then updated my R to 3.4.0. Did not work though.

Comment: i am not sure why it is not working for you.

Comment: so it's just me? I tried it on windows and it works fine.

Comment: I am also using windows.  Thanks for sharing that info

Comment: Same issue here: Files can be opened with Excel, but not with Numbers or Preview.

Comment: I raised a ticket: https://github.com/awalker89/openxlsx/issues/316