# Concatenate two dataframes and write back to xlsx file

Tags: r, concatenation, openxlsx

Currently I have code that allows me to read a text file and and xlsx file (openxlsx package) within a forloop. What I am trying to do is add the columns together and output the file as an xlsx, overwriting the original xlsx file. I want to do that within a forloop so that each file gets overwritten.

I do not want to add all these dataframes together into 1 giant dataframe, which is the most common query when most people ask this question, I just want to add the txtfile to the xlsfile and write the xlsx, overwriting the old xlsx file, and repeat it as necessary.

```
xls <- dir(pattern = "*xlsx")
txt <- dir(pattern = "*txt")
library("dplyr")
for (xlsfile in xls) {
  D1 <- read.xlsx(xlsfile, colNames = F, rowNames = F)
  for (txtfile in txt) {
    D2 <- read.csv(txtfile, header=F, skip=3, colClasses=c("NULL", rep(NA,3),
      rep("NULL",7), rep(NA,3), rep("NULL",6)
    # this is to keep columns for D2 in line with the columns in D1
    D3 <- bind_rows(D2, D1)
    write.xlsx(D3, xlsfile) 
  }
}
```

I tried to use `rbind_all` to create D3, but R said that `rbind_all` was deprecated? The first issue is that when D1 is read using the xlsx package, I get headers with X1-X6, which is fine because that is how many columns I have in my shortened txtfile in the form of D2. However, the headers for D2 are V2, V3, V4, V12, V13, V14. When using bind_rows, it creates 6 new column headers in the form of V2-4 and V12-14, instead of adding them to the X1-X6 columns, so the new information is 6 columns over right below where the xlsx dataframe ends.

I was told that the characters of the two files were different factors, which I am not sure why or how that happened, and I don't believe a simple gsub from "V" to "X" would work because I have different numbers following the V in my D2.

However, the forloop still runs with bind_rows, and for some reason, when I open up the xlsx files that I wrote overwriting the old ones, they all contain the same information and elements as my very last xlsfile+txtfile, meaning that all the new xlsx files were my the exact same, and contained my last files information, still with the extra columns. I believe that this is a separate issue with my code, but I am not sure how to make it so that it doesn't recreate the last file over and over. I think that this is caused by my code that at some point, the forloop finishes for the D3 creation, but has not written the xlsx file, then it loops through the write.xlsx function.

Here is the xlsx (D1) file in R.

```
structure(list(X1 = c("#version 2.4", "## Oncotator v1.5.3.0 | Flat File 
Reference hg19 | GENCODE v19 EFFECT | UniProt_AAxform 2014_12 | CCLE_By_GP 
09292010 | UniProt_AA 2014_12 | dbNSFP v2.4 | ESP 6500SI-V2 | dbSNP build 
142 | 1000Genome phase3 20130502 | ClinVar 12.03.20 | COSMIC v62_291112 | 
ORegAnno UCSC Track | ESP 6500SI-V2 | UniProt 2014_12 | HumanDNARepairGenes 
20110905 | TUMORScape 20100104 | CCLE_By_Gene 09292010 | MutSig Published 
Results 20110905 | COSMIC_Tissue 291112 | CGC full_2012-03-15 | 
COSMIC_FusionGenes v62_291112 | HGNC Sept172014 | ACHILLES_Lineage_Results 
110303 | TCGAScape 110405 | Ensembl ICGC MUCOPA | Familial_Cancer_Genes 
20110905 | gencode_xref_refseq metadata_v19 ", 
"Hugo_Symbol", "MTOR", "EPHA2", "ARID1A"), X2 = c("P3F5", NA, 
"Chromosome", "1", "1", "1"), X3 = c(NA, NA, "Start_position", 
"11307916", "16464389", "27107273"), X4 = c(NA, NA, "End_position", 
"11307916", "16464389", "27107273"), X5 = c(NA, NA, 
"Variant_Classification", 
"Missense_Mutation", "Missense_Mutation", "3'UTR"), X6 = c(NA, 
NA, "Variant_Type", "SNP", "SNP", "SNP"), X7 = c(NA, NA, "Reference_Allele", 
"C", "C", "G"), X8 = c(NA, NA, "Tumor_Seq_Allele2", "T", "T", 
"C"), X9 = c(NA, NA, "dbSNP_RS", NA, NA, "rs199555039"), X10 = c(NA, 
NA, "dbSNP_Val_Status", NA, NA, "byFrequency"), X11 = c(NA, NA, 
"Genome_Change", "g.chr1:11307916C>T", "g.chr1:16464389C>T", 
"g.chr1:27107273G>C"), X12 = c(NA, NA, "Protein_Change", "p.S359N", 
"p.S424N", NA), X13 = c(NA, NA, "COSMIC_overlapping_mutations", 
NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6", 
"X7", "X8", "X9", "X10", "X11", "X12", "X13"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

And txtfile shortened to D2 is

```
structure(list(V1 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 31L, 41L), .Label = c("## 
Oncotator v1.5.3.0 | Flat File Reference hg19 | GENCODE v19 EFFECT | 
UniProt_AAxform 2014_12 | CCLE_By_GP 09292010 | UniProt_AA 2014_12 | dbNSFP 
v2.4 | ESP 6500SI-V2 | dbSNP build 142 | 1000Genome phase3 20130502 | 
ClinVar 12.03.20 | COSMIC v62_291112 | ORegAnno UCSC Track | ESP 6500SI-V2 | 
UniProt 2014_12 | HumanDNARepairGenes 20110905 | TUMORScape 20100104 | 
CCLE_By_Gene 09292010 | MutSig Published Results 20110905 | COSMIC_Tissue 
291112 | CGC full_2012-03-15 | COSMIC_FusionGenes v62_291112 | HGNC 
Sept172014 | ACHILLES_Lineage_Results 110303 | TCGAScape 110405 | Ensembl 
ICGC MUCOPA | Familial_Cancer_Genes 20110905 | gencode_xref_refseq 
metadata_v19 ", 
"#version 2.4", "ALK", "APC", "ARID1A", "ATM", "BAP1", "BCOR", 
"C11orf30", "CDH1", "CDKN2B-AS1", "CHD1", "CNOT3", "CSF3R", "CTNNB1", 
"DOK6", "EP300", "EPCAM", "EPHA2", "EPHA7", "EPOR", "ERBB2", 
"ERCC2", "ETV6", "FANCA", "FGF6", "FOXO1", "GPR124", "HDAC4", 
"HNF1A", "Hugo_Symbol", "IKBKE", "KDM5C", "KDR", "KLF4", "KMT2B", 
"KMT2D", "LRP1B", "MAP2K4", "MET", "MTOR", "MYB", "NCOA3", "NF2", 
"NOTCH2", "NSD1", "NTRK2", "NTRK3", "NUTM1", "PARK2", "PAX8", 
"PBRM1", "PDGFRA", "PDGFRB", "PHF8", "PMS1", "PMS2", "POLE", 
"POT1", "PRKCA", "RAD51C", "RAF1", "RB1", "ROBO1", "RUNX1", "SLIT2", 
"SMC1A", "SYK", "SYNE1", "TCF7L2", "TP53", "Unknown", "USP7", 
"WHSC1", "ZMYM3"), class = "factor"), V5 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
23L, 2L), .Label = c("", "1", "10", "11", "12", "13", "15", "16", 
"17", "18", "19", "2", "20", "21", "22", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
"7", "8", "9", "Chromosome", "X"), class = "factor"), V6 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 99L, 6L), .Label = c("", "108121722", "110249856", "112174416", 
"112175711", "11307916", "113991570", "114849135", "11488524", 
"116418878", "11958126", "12038916", "120510314", "121426926", 
"123011945", "124481159", "12626167", "12641934", "12642536", 
"12650654", "133240692", "135537281", "141806602", "144003367", 
"149495558", "152646204", "161771035", "16464389", "172516645", 
"176636762", "190728482", "1918738", "20597970", "206666682", 
"22103913", "240003706", "27107273", "29432715", "29445154", 
"29541192", "30038169", "31526940", "34508048", "34646113", "34649335", 
"36176975", "36186234", "36193590", "36210950", "36937111", "37689156", 
"37884417", "39921415", "41162692", "41193074", "41217841", "41223629", 
"41266049", "41564531", "4554585", "45867603", "46264182", "47613623", 
"48955624", "49439908", "51012853", "52442493", "52501682", "52692305", 
"53225043", "53441750", "54008382", "54647625", "55133866", "55970836", 
"56774005", "6029518", "64685656", "64691239", "64695929", "64711567", 
"64723880", "67511099", "68863633", "70465919", "7588995", "76164351", 
"79067483", "87476563", "88663732", "89849429", "89851191", "9017149", 
"92561683", "93657891", "93969298", "98194682", "98209419", "Start_position"
), class = "factor"), V7 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 99L, 6L), .Label = c("", 
"108121722", "110249856", "112174416", "112175711", "11307916", 
"113991570", "114849135", "11488524", "116418878", "11958126", 
"12038916", "120510314", "121426926", "123011945", "124481159", 
"12626167", "12641934", "12642536", "12650654", "133240692", 
"135537281", "141806602", "144003367", "149495558", "152646204", 
"161771035", "16464389", "172516645", "176636762", "190728482", 
"1918738", "20597970", "206666682", "22103913", "240003706", 
"27107273", "29432715", "29445154", "29541192", "30038169", "31526940", 
"34508048", "34646113", "34649335", "36176975", "36186234", "36193590", 
"36210950", "36937111", "37689156", "37884417", "39921415", "41162692", 
"41193074", "41217841", "41223629", "41266049", "41564531", "4554585", 
"45867603", "46264182", "47613623", "48955624", "49439908", "51012853", 
"52442493", "52501682", "52692305", "53225043", "53441750", "54008382", 
"54647625", "55133866", "55970836", "56774005", "6029518", "64685656", 
"64691239", "64695929", "64711567", "64723880", "67511099", "68863633", 
"70465919", "7588995", "76164351", "79067483", "87476563", "88663732", 
"89849429", "89851191", "9017149", "92561683", "93657891", "93969298", 
"98194682", "98209419", "End_position"), class = "factor"), V9 = 
structure(c(1L, 
1L, 9L, 5L), .Label = c("", "3'UTR", "IGR", "Intron", "Missense_Mutation", 
"Nonsense_Mutation", "RNA", "Silent", "Variant_Classification"
), class = "factor"), V10 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("", 
"SNP", "Variant_Type"), class = "factor"), V11 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 5L, 3L), .Label = c("", "A", "C", "G", "Reference_Allele", 
"T"), class = "factor"), V13 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 6L, 5L), .Label = c("", 
"A", "C", "G", "T", "Tumor_Seq_Allele2"), class = "factor"), 
V14 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("", "dbSNP_RS", 
"rs116809738", "rs139387758", "rs141802026", "rs150631563", 
"rs199555039", "rs372456536", "rs550515708", "rs567211112", 
"rs571512044", "rs587782826", "rs79547774"), class = "factor"), 
V15 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("", "byFrequency", 
"dbSNP_Val_Status"), class = "factor"), V35 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 99L, 2L), .Label = c("", "g.chr1:11307916C>T", "g.chr1:120510314G>A", 
"g.chr1:16464389C>T", "g.chr1:206666682C>A", "g.chr1:27107273G>C", 
"g.chr1:36937111G>T", "g.chr10:114849135G>A", "g.chr10:123011945G>A", 
"g.chr11:108121722C>T", "g.chr11:76164351T>A", "g.chr12:12038916A>G", 
"g.chr12:121426926A>C", "g.chr12:133240692C>T", "g.chr12:4554585G>A", 
"g.chr12:49439908G>A", "g.chr13:41162692A>G", "g.chr13:41193074G>A", 
"g.chr13:41217841T>C", "g.chr13:41223629G>T", "g.chr13:48955624C>T", 
"g.chr15:34646113G>A", "g.chr15:34649335T>C", "g.chr15:88663732G>A", 
"g.chr16:31526940C>T", "g.chr16:68863633T>A", "g.chr16:89849429G>A", 
"g.chr16:89851191C>T", "g.chr16:9017149C>T", "g.chr17:11958126G>A", 
"g.chr17:37884417C>T", "g.chr17:56774005C>T", "g.chr17:64685656C>T", 
"g.chr17:64691239G>A", "g.chr17:64695929A>T", "g.chr17:64711567C>T", 
"g.chr17:64723880G>A", "g.chr17:7588995C>T", "g.chr18:67511099A>G", 
"g.chr19:11488524C>T", "g.chr19:34508048G>A", "g.chr19:36210950A>G", 
"g.chr19:45867603A>G", "g.chr19:54647625C>T", "g.chr2:113991570C>T", 
"g.chr2:141806602C>T", "g.chr2:190728482G>A", "g.chr2:240003706G>A", 
"g.chr2:29432715G>A", "g.chr2:29445154C>T", "g.chr2:29541192G>T", 
"g.chr2:47613623A>C", "g.chr20:46264182A>C", "g.chr20:51012853G>A", 
"g.chr20:52501682G>A", "g.chr21:36176975G>A", "g.chr21:36186234T>G", 
"g.chr21:36193590A>G", "g.chr22:30038169T>C", "g.chr22:41564531C>T", 
"g.chr3:12626167G>A", "g.chr3:12641934C>T", "g.chr3:12642536G>T", 
"g.chr3:12650654C>T", "g.chr3:41266049C>G", "g.chr3:52442493G>A", 
"g.chr3:52692305G>A", "g.chr3:79067483T>C", "g.chr4:172516645G>A", 
"g.chr4:1918738G>A", "g.chr4:20597970G>A", "g.chr4:55133866T>C", 
"g.chr4:55970836C>T", "g.chr5:112174416G>T", "g.chr5:112175711G>A", 
"g.chr5:149495558A>G", "g.chr5:176636762T>C", "g.chr5:98194682A>G", 
"g.chr5:98209419G>A", "g.chr6:135537281C>T", "g.chr6:152646204G>A", 
"g.chr6:161771035C>T", "g.chr6:93969298C>G", "g.chr7:116418878T>A", 
"g.chr7:124481159G>T", "g.chr7:6029518C>T", "g.chr7:92561683G>A", 
"g.chr8:144003367A>G", "g.chr8:37689156T>A", "g.chr9:110249856C>T", 
"g.chr9:22103913G>A", "g.chr9:87476563G>A", "g.chr9:93657891G>A", 
"g.chrX:39921415G>A", "g.chrX:53225043G>A", "g.chrX:53441750T>C", 
"g.chrX:54008382T>C", "g.chrX:70465919G>A", "Genome_Change"
), class = "factor"), V42 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 40L, 34L), .Label = c("", 
"p.A1150V", "p.A1474T", "p.A301T", "p.A353T", "p.A403D", 
"p.A510A", "p.A624T", "p.C654Y", "p.D1014D", "p.D454D", "p.G581D", 
"p.H84H", "p.I1148N", "p.I185I", "p.K123R", "p.K234R", "p.K403K", 
"p.L360P", "p.L413I", "p.L518L", "p.L791H", "p.L868L", "p.M102I", 
"p.P16A", "p.P542Q", "p.P672P", "p.P868S", "p.Q1545*", "p.Q410P", 
"p.R1469W", "p.S1042I", "p.S1318L", "p.S359N", "p.S424N", 
"p.S51L", "p.T1258I", "p.T273T", "p.V1521A", "Protein_Change"
), class = "factor"), V57 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
"COSMIC_overlapping_mutations", "p.?(1)", "p.?(2)", "p.0?(10)|p.?(1)", 
"p.0?(15)|p.?(4)", "p.0?(2)|p.?(1)", "p.A5_A80del(53)|p.A5_Q143del(7)|p.A5_A80>D(7)|p.?(4)|p.T3_A126del(2)|p.A5fs*7(2)|p.M5_N141>D(2)|p.L10_N141del(2)|p.A5_Y142>D(2)|p.A5_Q143>E(1)|p.A13_R151del(1)|p.D6_S29del(1)|p.M14_S45del(1)|p.M1_A87del(1)|p.D11_Y142>H(1)|p.A5_T59del(1)|p.M1_V173del(1)|p.E15_I140>V(1)|p.A5_T40del(1)|p.A5_E54del(1)|p.M8_A80del(1)|p.P16_K133del(1)|p.A5_I35del(1)", 
"p.K1454fs*3(1)|p.K1192fs*3(1)|p.?(1)", "p.P542R(1)"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V5", "V6", "V7", "V9", "V10", "V11", "V13", "V14", "V15", "V35", 
"V42", "V57"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

I believe that you may say to skip a few lines when reading them both so that I can add them together easier, as the third row is all the same, but I need to keep the first two headers which I only know how to do that doing

```
FileName = file.choose()
input = file(FileName, open = "r")
Header = readLines(input, 2)
Data <- read.csv(input)
close(input)

output = file(FileName, open = "w")
writeLines(Header, output)
write.csv(Data, output, row.names = F)
close(output)
```

And I don't know how to do this in a forloop

Comment: You don't mean "add", you mean "concatenate", specifically "concatenate columns". And it really doesn't have to be in a for-loop. So your question is "concatenate multiple files". There are [179 existing questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+concatenate+files+is%3Aq) on [tag:r] concatenate files, please read them.

Comment: If you want to open a file for both read-and-write, use [`open(..., mode = 'r+')`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/connections.html), although that's seriously dangerous until your code is fully debugged, so for now just write to a separate output file. (Actually [openxlsx sounds a little buggy anyway, so I wouldn't try to overwrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44479997/cannot-open-the-file-after-writing-xlsx-file-using-r-openxlsx-package))

Comment: If you want to override the colnames on D2 to be those of D1, then either supply [`col.names` to your `read.csv`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html), e.g. `D2 <- read.csv(... col.names=names(D1), ...)`. And/or manipulate `names(D2)` , or some slice e.g. `names(D2)[1:6]` after the read.